# Single instance not working in C#, program can't access itself

Tags: c#, single-instance

I am trying to get a program to open a file in the current instance rather than a new instance, and here is what I have so far, which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424368/opening-a-known-file-type-into-running-instance-of-custom-app-net/424427#424427).

```
static class Program
    {
        static EsfEditorSingleton controller;
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            // Show the main form of the app.
            controller = new EsfEditorSingleton();
            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            controller.Run(args);
            controller.StartupNextInstance += controller.NextInstanceStartup;
        }

    }
    public class EsfEditorSingleton : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        internal EsfEditorSingleton() : base()
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;
            this.MainForm = new EsfEditorForm();
        }
        public void NextInstanceStartup(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
        {
            EsfEditorForm form = (EsfEditorForm)this.MainForm;
            string[] args = null;
            e.CommandLine.CopyTo(args, 0);
            form.mProcessArgs(args);
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Here is the part that the above calls.

```
public class EsfEditorForm : Form
{

    public EsfEditorForm()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        mProcessArgs(args);
    }

    public void mProcessArgs(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[i])) { this.OpenFile(args[i]); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit F5 in VS 2010 Pro (FYI), it compiles and starts, and then gives me this IOException was not handled error in Visual Studio:

The process cannot access the file 'I:\Program Files\Totar\EFS Editor\VS - Solution\bin\x86\Release\EsfEditor 1.4.8.exe' because it is being used by another process.

I believe the file mentioned is the executable that is running at the moment.

**StackTrace**:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
at EsfEditor.Parser.EsfParser..ctor(String filename)
at EsfEditor.Core.EsfObjects.EsfFile..ctor(String filePath)
at EsfEditor.Forms.EsfEditorForm.OpenFile(String filePath)
at EsfEditor.Forms.EsfEditorForm.mProcessArgs(String[] args)
at EsfEditor.Forms.EsfEditorForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
at EsfEditor.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what process is using your executable file?

Comment: Why are you Debigging in Release mode?

Comment: There is no other process using it. As for the debugging, no reason really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you skip first parameter in mProcessArgs?

```
public void mProcessArgs(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = **1**; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[i])) { this.OpenFile(args[i]); }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's it. About as soon as I asked the question I realized why it was doing that, but I figured I'd carry through and see if anyone guessed it. Besides, this may help others in the future. I didn't think about the Length > 1 though.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() is the executable being run. You need to modify your Main method to pass in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1) to your controller.Run() method