# Pass commands to .NET GUI from external editor

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interprocess

I there any way to start an instance of a C# .NET-program and then call it again using a command-line option to, for example, insert a text in a text box?

Use case:
1) Double click / start: MyProgram.exe (will start the GUI)
2) From command line: MyProgram.exe -addText "Text to add" (my "favorite" editor will launch this command when I press some keyboard combination)

I.e. I want to pass commands to an already running instance of my (GUI) program.

I have been thinking about WCF but can't see any solution there...

Of course I can create a file which my program polls every X ms, reads the contents, performs the command and deletes it but isn't there any more elegant solution?

Comment: Have you used Google with "wcf ipc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the same as having a single instance of an application responding to the launch of an associated file type.

See [Opening a "known file type" into running instance of custom app - .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424368/opening-a-known-file-type-into-running-instance-of-custom-app-net) or search here for `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` which is what handles the wiring up of instances for you.

Comment: This link helped me: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx