# How to update a WinForms control of a running application when another instance of this executable program is launched?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, multiple-instances, single-instance

I made single instance app, but my problem is, I don't know how to get the first opened FormMain instance and update the form TextBox!
Could you help me?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool result;
    Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "unique_name", out result);

    if (!result)
    {
        **/* 
          CALL OPENED FORM INSTANCE AND UPDATE TEXTBOX
         */**

        return;
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
    Application.Run(new FormMain(args));

    GC.KeepAlive(mutex);
}
```

Comment: You could send a standard Windows message to the main window of the other process and make the original update its own controls. It's not possible to do from another process.

Comment: Use the [StartupNextInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance?view=net-5.0) event, as shown in [this C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424427/2330053).

Comment: @Alejandro I suspect that a WM_ COPYDATA message would be needed.

Comment: @MartinJames That could be a good candidate if a large chunk of data needs to be passed, or a custom one if just a notification suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use named pipeline interprocess communication like that:

**Usings**

```
using System;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading;
```

**Static variables**

```
static public bool AllowApplicationMultipleInstances { get; private set; } = true;

static private Mutex ApplicationMutex;

static private NamedPipeServerStream IPCServer;
```

**Application unique identifier**

```
static public string GetGUID()
{
  object[] attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false);
  return ( (GuidAttribute)attributes[0] ).ToString();
}
```

**Check only one instance and init the server**

```
static private bool CheckApplicationOnlyOneInstance(AsyncCallback duplicated)
{
  AllowApplicationMultipleInstances = false;
  string guid = GetGUID();
  ApplicationMutex = new Mutex(true, guid, out bool created);
  if ( created )
    CreateIPCServer(duplicated);
  else
  {
    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", guid, PipeDirection.InOut);
    client.Connect();
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(client, "BringToFront");
    client.Close();
  }
  return created;
}
```

**Create the server**

```
static private void CreateIPCServer(AsyncCallback duplicated)
{
  IPCServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(GetGUID(),
                                        PipeDirection.InOut,
                                        1,
                                        PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                                        PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
  IPCServer.BeginWaitForConnection(duplicated, IPCServer);
}
```

**Anwser to a request**

```
static private void IPCRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  var server = ar.AsyncState as NamedPipeServerStream;
  server.EndWaitForConnection(ar);
  var command = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(server) as string;
  if ( command == "BringToFront" )
  {
    Console.WriteLine(command);
    //MainForm.Instance.SyncUI(() => MainForm.Instance.MenuShowHide_Click(null, null));
  }
  server.Close();
  CreateIPCServer(IPCRequest);
}
```

**Test**

```
static private void Test()
{
  if ( !SystemManager.CheckApplicationOnlyOneInstance(IPCRequest) )
    return;
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Usage**

You can create as string commands as needed.

For example it allows to pass command line arguments from a process just started to the actual running process.

Also you can improve this simple behavior to have a more complex system, to use a classes framework instead of string commands.

For your application you should be able to use:

```
static public FormMain MainForm;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if ( !SystemManager.CheckApplicationOnlyOneInstance(IPCRequest) )
    return;
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
  MainForm = new FormMain(args);
  Application.Run(MainForm);
}
```

If you modify a WinForm control you must to synchronize with the main UI thread:

[How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread)

[How to access a WinForms control from another thread i.e. synchronize with the GUI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657831/how-to-access-a-winforms-control-from-another-thread-i-e-synchronize-with-the-g/58658119#58658119)

**Some links**

[PipeStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream)

[Full Duplex Asynchronous Read/Write with Named Pipes (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1179195/Full-Duplex-Asynchronous-Read-Write-with-Named-Pip)

[Inter Process Communication (C# Vault)](https://csharpvault.com/inter-process-communication/)

[WCF Comparison with Web Services and .NET Remoting (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45698/WCF-Comparison-with-Web-Services-and-NET-Remoting)

[Socket Programming In C# (C-SharpCorner)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/socket-programming-in-C-Sharp/)

[Socket Programming in C# (GeeksForGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/)

[Simple Client-server Interactions using C# (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C)