# How can I send data to a console application that is already running?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to create an application that is just a queue and it will have worker threads processing messages in the queue. That by itself shouldn't be a problem, but the queue will not originate from filesystem. What I would like to do is bypass the filesystem entirely and send the data to the application, to be added to the queue. I want to bypass the filesystem because I have a scheduler that can run dozens of times per second which would be used to add to the queue eventually.

How can I send data to this application while it is already running?

Comment: Listen on a network port, e.g. creating a simple web server listening for requests to add to the queue?

Comment: [Full Duplex Named Pipes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1179195/Full-Duplex-Asynchronous-Read-Write-with-Named-Pip) | [Inter Process Com](https://csharpvault.com/inter-process-communication/) | [WCF Comparison with Web Services and Remoting](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45698/WCF-Comparison-with-Web-Services-and-NET-Remoting) | [Socket](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/socket-programming-in-C-Sharp/) | [Socket](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/) | [Client-server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a WinForms control of a running application when another instance of this executable program is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220025/) and [C# - WCF - inter-process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613586/) and [What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/)

Comment: After re-reading the question, if your system is as stressful as you mention it is, you should consider using a database to populate a table as a queue that is monitored by the monitoring process. Also you can take a look at [MSMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) if Windows.

Comment: Remoting seemed simple to develop and lightweight so I was going to give that a try first, however as I was halfway through copying some sample code I discovered that it is not available in .net core; so I will be falling back onto pipes and giving that a try