# Connect two console applications in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have two C# console application: A and B where console application A has a continuously running method which is filling `integer` values in a static circular queue-(`StaticQueue`).
In console application B,I have a circular queue again named as `LocalQueue`. I need to pull the values from the `StaticQueue` from Console Application A one at a time, check if the `LocalQueue` is empty or not in Console Application B, if not empty add the value pulled from `StaticQueue` into `LocalQueue` until the size of the `LocalQueue` is not met.

How can I achieve this in C#? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: use sockets. for passing data between 2 apps

Comment: In case it helps: [How to update a WinForms control of a running application when another instance of this executable program is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220025/how-to-update-a-winforms-control-of-a-running-application-when-another-instance/65220487#65220487)

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Message Queue](https://zeromq.org/languages/csharp/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm using socket connection for my application.